# Flutter not rendering SVG start and end markers

Tags: flutter, svg

I have created a basic path with arrow markers on each end ( <--> ), when I try render it in flutter it cuts off the markers and just renders a line ( -- ).

[image]

```
Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight,
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/hoz_arrow.svg',
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

remove
max height and max width. wrap with expanded.

```
  Expanded(  
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/hoz_arrow.svg',
        ),
      )
```